# Kineticjs tween not working when I add a second tween

Tags: kineticjs, tween

I have two tweens that seem to be conflicting with one another. 
When I only create one or the other they both work fine. If I create both the first tween (flipUp) no longer moves the x. the second one (match) works fine. if I change match and remove the x: and y: and make it opacity, they both work fine.

Case1: the x: in flip up is ignored.

```
this.flipUp = new Kinetic.Tween({
                              node: this.group,
                              duration: 0.5,
                                scaleX: 0,
                                x: this.position.x + (width/2),
                               onFinish: this.endFlipUp.bind(this)
                              });

this.match = new Kinetic.Tween({
                                node: this.group,
                                duration: 0.5,
                                x: 0 - width*2,
                                y: 0 - height*2,
                                onFinish: this.endMatch.bind(this)
                                });
```

case 2: works fine.

```
this.flipUp = new Kinetic.Tween({
                              node: this.group,
                              duration: 0.5,
                                scaleX: 0,
                                x: this.position.x + (width/2),
                               onFinish: this.endFlipUp.bind(this)
                              });

this.match = new Kinetic.Tween({
                                node: this.group,
                                duration: 0.5,
                                opacity: 0,
                                onFinish: this.endMatch.bind(this)
                                });
```

using latest version 5.1 of kineticjs

Answer (score 0):

In first case you are using two tweens with `x` property. If you are starting that tweens at same time you will have unexpected behaviour. What are you expecting on `x` property at the end of tweens working? `this.position.x + (width/2)` or `0 - width*2`? Use such tween at different time or with different properties.

Comment: I am using them at different times.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?